# Python scipy module installation for Python2.7 and Python 3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pip

I have Python 3.4 and Python 2.7 in C:\Python34 and C:\Python27 directories respectively. Now I wanted to install scipy and numpy modules, and use them with both the versions of python. Now where should I install scipy and numpy? In which folder should I run 'pip install' command?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can possibly do is use [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to create both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 environments respectively (I think you use the -p flag to specify the base executable). Once you've done so, you can activate each environment and do a "pip install", which will install the packages to each virtual environment.

Comment: This is a duplicate of other questions.  Run pip in both /python27 and /python34 to get separate sets of binaries.  You may want to point it to www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs.